# How does the sample code for izip work?

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to understand the "equivalent code" for [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from the docs.

```
def izip(*iterables):
    # izip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while iterators:
        yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

Since `iterators` is a non-empty list, shouldn't this produce an infinite loop?
Also I tried to put `print iterators` to the bottom of the function, but it never got executed. Why?

Comment: Martijn gave you the answer, but the answer to your other question _"I tried to put `print iterators` to the bottom of the function, but it never got executed."_ - `yield` will return from the method; so unless you put it before the `yield`, your statement won't get executed.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, that's not strictly true. If he had put it in the bottom of the function, with the same indentation of the `yield`, it would execute on the next call.

Answer (score 3):

When an iterator is exhausted, it raises `StopIteration` when `next()` is called on it.

Thus, the `tuple(map(next, iterators))` will propagate the `StopIteration` exception to the caller, interrupting the infinite loop.